# How does IPv4 know it has received a fragment?

Tags: ipv4

So I'm reading about IPv4 and one of the questions are about how IPv4 knows that a fragment has arrived.

Is it a certain header that is set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AIUI

There are three fields in the IPv4 header that are relavent to fragment detection and reassembly.

- The "fragment offset", a number where a fragment fits into the complete packet.
- The "more fragments" flag, a single bit flag that specifies whether there are more fragments after this one.
- The "ID" field, this identifies which packet a fragment belongs to.

If "fragment offset" and "more fragments" are both zero then it is a complete un-fragmented packet. Otherwise we are dealing with a fragment.